# Create Pivot Table on Excel 2013 (Runtime Error 91)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have written a script to create a new pivot table, but I keep getting Runtime error 91 for the part where I add the Pivot fields.

Appreciate all your help!

**My Code**

```
Sub CreatePT()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PTF As PivotFields

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsPT As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range

'Set the worksheet that contains data source
Set wsData = Worksheets("Raw Data")
Set wsPT = Worksheets("Pivot Talble")
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'Set source data range
Set rngData = wsData.Range("A1:G50")

Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'Raw Data'!A$1$:K$20$")

Set pt = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(wsPT.Range("B3"))

'Add in Filters to Pivot Table
With pt
    With pt.PivotFields("Month")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With pt.PivotFields("Cost")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: when you run the code in debug mode at what line are you getting the error ? you also have `With pt` and then after `With pt.PivotFields("Month")` , you are already nested under the first `With` so you can write it `With .PivotFields("Month")`

Comment: Hi Shai, the line getting the error is the With pt.PivotFields("Month").

Comment: even if you change it to `With .PivotFields("Month")` ?

Comment: Yes, i still get runtime error 91.

Comment: test the code in my answer below and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modifed the lines how you set-up your `PivotCache` and `PivotTable` , it seems they were the reason for your error.

Not sure where lies your `PivotTable` source data ? is it Range("A1:G50") in "Raw Data" worksheet, or Range("A1:K20")  ?  Do you want it to be dynamic to find the last row with data in "Raw Data" worksheet?

I also added a procedure to trap if the `PivotTable` was already created in previous code runs, if yes then the `PivotTable` will only refresh itself. If the `PivotTable` isn't created (first time running this code) it will create the `PivotTable` with all `PivotFields`.

***Note***: you have worksheet ("Pivot Talble") , I think it might be a Typo, shouldn't it be "Pivot Table" ?

### **Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePT()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PTF As PivotFields

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsPT As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range

'Set the worksheet that contains data source
Set wsData = Worksheets("Raw Data")
Set wsPT = Worksheets("Pivot Talble")
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'Set source data range
Set rngData = wsData.Range("A1:G50")

'Set pivot cache
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro set PivotTable
On Error Resume Next
Set pt = wsPT.PivotTables("PivotTable 1")  ' Pivot Table already created (from previous code runs)

On Error GoTo 0
' first time running this code >> create the Pivot Table
If pt Is Nothing Then

    Set pt = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(wsPT.Range("B3"), "PivotTable 1")
    'Add in Filters to Pivot Table
    With pt
        With .PivotFields("Month")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With .PivotFields("Cost")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
        End With
    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (data in "Raw Data" sheet)
    pt.ChangePivotCache PTCache
    pt.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes your code works perfectly! Thanks a lot! I think the error was with the Pivotcache in my code.